# Hibernate: SELECT after DELETE finds deleted object first time

Tags: java, hibernate

`Tag` is an entity and I remove tags with this method:

```
public static <T> boolean deleteById(Class<? extends BaseEntity> clazz, Long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            T e = get(clazz, id);
            if (e != null) { 
                session.delete(e);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

Next thing, I read the list with Tags again with this method:

```
public static List<Tag> listTags() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("FROM Tag tag"); 
        List<Tag> tags = (List<Tag>) q.list();
        session.close();
        return tags;
}
```

The problem is that when deleting and reselecting all Tags the removed Tag is in the list although not in the database. when I run listTags() a second time, by clicking a link the object is removed and I get the correct list.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please clarify a point for me -- When you see the deleted item still in the list, when is this ? Is it after re-querying, or are you breakpointing, or something else. This will help to figure what is going on.

Comment: How about adding a `session.flush()` after the delete?

Comment: Abdelhak solved it. @jr593 First I delete and then open a new session and read the entire Tag list with HQL: "FROM Tag tag"

Comment: @jpkrohling I tried that, didn't work. The difference was in getTransaction and beginTransaction methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `flush()` and use `commit()` like below:

```
  ...
  session.delete(e);
  session.flush();
  session.beginTransaction().commit();
  ...
```

For more info go to [session.getTransaction() vs session.beginTransaction()](http://www.connect2java.com/tutorials/hibernate/gettransaction-begintransaction-and-getidentifier-in-hibernate/)

Comment: Thanks, `session.beginTransaction().commit();` did it. Why does that work and not getTransaction()?

Comment: @JackFlamp see the link above

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Hibernate while migration from MySQL to MariaDB, were multiple transactions were being open and not closed...

the solution was removing the opening of the transactions as they were not required anyway....